# SD Card showing weird file names and files are lost

Tags: laptop, video, sd-card, camera

I just plugged my SD Card to my PC after a long videography day, and I suddenly got this problem:

[image: Problem screenshot]

It is also not showing all the videos I took on my camera so what is the solution?

Comment: The data on the card is corrupted. Restore form backup, or try to restore the data using testdisk/photorec or alike..  See the suggested duplicate...

Comment: *Golden rule:* Because most SD cards are a pile of $%^&, make certain to only ever use those on your camera manufacturer's recommended list - & don't buy them from eBay, buy them from a reputable camera store.